# Telnet error  when connecting from Windows to Unix

Tags: windows, unix, telnet

When I try to connect through telnet from a Windows system to Unix, I am not able to connect. I am getting this log error. Is this related to a firewall issue, or anything I need to mention in the `etc\service` file?

```
"Telnet is busy with its port23"
```

Does that mean that telnet is not properly working, or do I need to mention a different name here?

Comment: There's nothing to take care about. OSs do not matter. TCP/IP is transparent about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a network issue, not a telnet one.
Either your Windows firewall (or any other you are using) is blocking telnet, or your router is configured to block it.

Comment: you mean NIC card, because ping is working but no telnet,, do we need to check etc\host or service file in such a way that ip address conflicting

Comment: NIC card? :S Anyway, try with netcat to open a TCP connection to port 23.

Comment: may be you are correct we need to think in that way checking firewll or any othere